# React -- changing state unrelated to component triggers maximum update depth error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I think I'm misunderstanding something here.

I have a child receiving 1) a boolean to notify of the parent's submit event, and 2) a callback to send up information when the submit event is occurring

```
<VariationForm      
    isSubmitting={this.state.isSubmitting}
    submittingHandler={this.receiveChildFormSubmit}
/>;
```

When the parent submit event fires:

```
submitForm = () => {
    this.setState({isSubmitting: true})
}
```

The child component will receive this new `isSubmitting` state, triggering a callback that will pass the 'sub form' data up to the parent.

```
// in the parent
receiveChildFormSubmit = (formData) => {
    this.setState({product_variations: formData})
}
```

The child component listens for this `isSubmitting` piece of state to change, at which point it will pass up the relevant data from `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        if (nextProps.isSubmitting)
            this.props.submittingHandler(this.state.product_variations)
```

I get that this maybe a bit of an antipattern, but the child part of the form is such a behavior-heavy part of the form that I wanted to separate them.

The problem is, I am getting `Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.`

It sounds like maybe the fact that the handler, triggered by a state change in it's parent, is then changing the state of its parent, causing another trigger, producing an infinite loop.

What I don't understand though, is that the state that this callback changes `product_variations` is never being passed to the `VariationForm`, so why would it get passed props again?

Any idea of how to prevent this loop scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your child component `componentWillReceiveProps` you seem to be calling the parent function which updates the state and triggeres re-render in parent causing the child components `componentWillReceiveProps` to be called again and thus going on a loop.

You need to add a check in the child component `componentWillReceiveProps` like

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        if ((nextProps.isSubmitting !== this.props.isSubmitting) && nextProps.isSubmitting)
            this.props.submittingHandler(this.state.product_variations)
         }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help again Shubham!

Comment: @DanielThompson, glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

In your childComponent you are checking if "isSubmitting" is true then you are calling parentHanlder.In ParentHandler you are changing state of a different property but still this state change will cause your parent to re-render and also re-render childComponent where again you are checking "isSubmitting" value which still true due to last setState call hence it kinda forms a loop.

Therefore in your "componentWillReceiveProps" you need to check whether this props that are your recieving are they any different than what your recieved earlier if so only then call parent handler.

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
        if ((nextProps.isSubmitting !== this.props.isSubmitting) && nextProps.isSubmitting)
            this.props.submittingHandler(this.state.product_variations)
         }
}
```